# I have placed OJDBC jar in library of both maven and benerator still I am getting error as Class not found: 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

Tags: maven, ojdbc

I am generating test data from db by using benerator tool with maven.
I have placed ojdbc jars in lib of both the installable still I am getting error as :

> Failed to execute goal org.databene:maven-benerator-plugin:0.7.7:generate (default-cli) on project AA: Execution default-cli of goal org.databene:maven-benerator-plugin:0.7.7:generate failed: Connecting the database failed. URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe: Connecting jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe failed: Class not found: 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

Comment: Try to put it in the lib of jdk if nothing else works

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your maven `pom.xml` ([**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Answer (score 1):

Please check the  section under  in your plugin configuration

Comment: “<datasource> <url>" section

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).